# sending extra argument to event handler with event argument

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

i have this input with `onchange` event handler

```
  <input accept="image/*" type='file' id="imgInp" @change="imageChange" />
```

my `imageChange` method is like

```
  methods : {
   imageChange(e ){
      const file = e.target.files[0];
      console.log(file);
      URL.createObjectURL(file);
      this.model.image = URL.createObjectURL(file);

     } , 

  }
```

basically setting `model.image` value on change now i want to have multiple images on my model ... so i want to change the image property to array and have an input for each image

```
<div v-for="(image , index) in model.images" v-bind:key="index">
  <input accept="image/*" type='file' id="imgInp" @change="imageChange" />
</div>
```

now i need to send the imaeg index in the array to my function as well so i can replace that index image like

and change my method to

```
  imageChange(e , index ){
      console.log(`event ->`);
      console.log(e);
      console.log(`index ->`);
      console.log(index);
      //URL...
      this.model.images[index] = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  }
```

but this will result in undefined event here is the output

```
event ->
undefined
index ->
0
```

how can i send extra argument to event handler without losing event argument ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just execute the function inside with `@change` event, and pass the Vue provided `$event` params first then `index` param.

```
<div v-for="(image , index) in model.images" v-bind:key="index">
  <input accept="image/*" type='file' id="imgInp" @change="imageChange($event, index)" />
</div>
```